# Appending an empty row after every 5 or 10 rows in LaTeX table

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable, automation, knitr

I wonder how to append an empty row after every 5 or 10 rows in `LaTeX` table. Here is my MWE in `.Rnw` format. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

<< label=LongTable, results='asis', echo = FALSE >>=
library(xtable)
set.seed(12345)
MatrixData <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)

print(
  xtable(
      x = MatrixData
    , caption = "Example of longtable spanning several pages"
    #, label = "tab:MatrixData"
    , align = c("l|", rep("r", ncol(MatrixData)))
    , digits = c(rep(3, ncol(MatrixData)+1))
  )

  , table.placement = "H"
  , caption.placement = "top"
  , include.rownames = TRUE
  , include.colnames = TRUE
  , size = "small"
  , tabular.environment = 'longtable'
  , floating = FALSE
  , add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),command = 
                        paste("\\hline  \\endfirsthead"  ,                          # First caption
                                "\\caption[]{Example of longtable spanning several pages} \\label{tab:MatrixData} \\\\ \\hline", # Additional captions
                                paste("&", 1:ncol(MatrixData),collapse=" "),                              # Column names
                                "\\\\ \\hline ",
                                "\\endhead", 
                                "\\hline \\multicolumn{11}{r}{\\textit{Continued}} \\                    
                                 \\endfoot
                                 \\endlastfoot",collapse=" ")))
@

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following solution sets up an environment `blocktable` derived from `longtable` that provides the desired functionality using LaTeX only.

### Implementation notes

First, a few counters are needed:

```
\newcounter{@tabrow}
\newcounter{@emptyrow}
\newcounter{@modulus}
\newcounter{@default@blocksize}
```

`@tabrow` will be incremented every row to determine the current row number while `@emptyrow` will hold multiples of `@modulus` (which accordingly is set to the number of rows one block/chunk should contain; to be precise it will be `@modulus+1`). Last mentioned is set internally through `\@setblocksize`:

```
\newcommand{\@setblocksize}[1]{%
  \setcounter{@modulus}{#1}
  \setcounter{@emptyrow}{\the@modulus}
  \stepcounter{@modulus}
}
```

`@default@blocksize` holds the global default value that will be given to `@modulus` if no optional argument is specified (see below: `blocktable`).

The core macro is `\empty@or@void@line` which expands to an empty line, i.e. `&...&\\`, if `\the@tabrow` is a multiple of `\the@modulus` and to simply nothing if not:

```
\def\empty@or@void@line{%
  \ifnum\the@tabrow=\the@emptyrow
    \addtocounter{@emptyrow}{\the@modulus}%
    \@colseps\ltx@LT@tabularcr
  \fi}
```

It will be added to every occurance of `\\` by saying:

```
\def\LT@tabularcr{\ltx@LT@tabularcr\empty@or@void@line}
```

As seen, in `\empty@or@void@line` internally the empty row internally gets constructed via `\@colseps\ltx@LT@tabularcr` where `\ltx@LT@tabularcr` is a stored version of `\LT@tabularcr` and `\@colseps` contains the right number of `&`s which is done with the help of `longtable`'s `\LT@cols` (which holds the number of columns!) by an auxiliary command:

```
\newcommand\build@colseps{%
  \@tempcnta\@ne
  \loop
    \advance\@tempcnta by 1
    \g@addto@macro\@colseps{&}
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<\the\LT@cols\repeat
}
```

The core functionality is applied to a new environment `blocktable` based on `longtable`:

```
\newenvironment{blocktable}[2][\the@default@blocksize]
  {\@setblocksize{#1}\build@colseps\longtable{@{\stepcounter{@tabrow}}#2}}
  {\endlongtable \gdef\@colseps{} \setcounter{@tabrow}{0}}
```

which assembles all the work done before. It also cleans up the `@tabrow` count and `\@colseps` macro -- which was also allocated empty beforehand.

To make sure that the blocking/chunking begins at the right row the following lines conclude the solution code:

```
\g@addto@macro\endfirsthead{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
\g@addto@macro\endhead{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
\g@addto@macro\endfoot{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
\g@addto@macro\endlastfoot{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
```

### Example

#### Figure

Before the complete code here is an example pic produced using the default chunk size of 5:

[image: output]

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{@tabrow}
\newcounter{@emptyrow}
\newcounter{@modulus}
\newcounter{@default@blocksize}
\setcounter{@default@blocksize}{5}
\def\@colseps{}

\let\ltx@LT@tabularcr=\LT@tabularcr

\def\empty@or@void@line{%
  \ifnum\the@tabrow=\the@emptyrow
    \addtocounter{@emptyrow}{\the@modulus}%
    \@colseps\ltx@LT@tabularcr
  \fi}
\def\LT@tabularcr{\ltx@LT@tabularcr\empty@or@void@line}
\newenvironment{blocktable}[2][\the@default@blocksize]
  {\@setblocksize{#1}\build@colseps\longtable{@{\stepcounter{@tabrow}}#2}}
  {\endlongtable \gdef\@colseps{} \setcounter{@tabrow}{0}}
\newcommand\build@colseps{%
  \@tempcnta\@ne
  \loop
    \advance\@tempcnta by 1
    \g@addto@macro\@colseps{&}
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<\the\LT@cols\repeat
}
\newcommand{\@setblocksize}[1]{%
  \setcounter{@modulus}{#1}
  \setcounter{@emptyrow}{\the@modulus}
  \stepcounter{@modulus}
}
\newcommand{\defaultBTblocksize}[1]{\setcounter{@default@blocksize}{#1}}
\g@addto@macro\endfirsthead{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
\g@addto@macro\endhead{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
\g@addto@macro\endfoot{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}
\g@addto@macro\endlastfoot{\setcounter{@tabrow}{1}}

\makeatother

%\defaultBTblocksize{10}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{blocktable}{ccc}
  \caption{Boring example table}\\
  \toprule
  \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & \textbf{col3}\\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  foo & bar & baz\\
  \bottomrule
\end{blocktable}
\end{document}
```

### Remarks

1. I don't use knitr and therefore I did not test the solution with a table generated from an external data file like in the OP's mwe, but it should work without any problems when you declare `tabular.environment = 'blocktable'`.
2. When inserting an actual blank line there is the caveat that material inserted by `@{...}` also affects the lines left out (which isn't desiderable in my eyes) and the row numbering is just wrong and tricks are needed. #
3. To not overload this answer I packaged an alternative solution merged with the old one into a github repository: https://github.com/giannotr/blocktable (as a package called `blocktable`. *This isn't an official package* and it's neither properly documented nor tested. You get the original solution by chosing the 'emptyline' option).

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using `knitr`, the simplest thing is to add `\\` every tenth row using `add.to.row` parameter of `print.xtable`.

This is a very rough code;  in the general case you need also to check that `MatrixData` has more than 10 rows.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

<< label=LongTable, results='asis', echo = FALSE >>=
library(xtable)
set.seed(12345)
MatrixData <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)

caption <- paste("\\hline  \\endfirsthead"  ,                          # First caption
                                "\\caption[]{Example of longtable spanning several pages} \\label{tab:MatrixData} \\\\ \\hline", # Additional captions
                                paste("&", 1:ncol(MatrixData),collapse=" "),                              # Column names
                                "\\\\ \\hline ",
                                "\\endhead", 
                                "\\hline \\multicolumn{11}{r}{\\textit{Continued}} \\                    
                                 \\endfoot
                                 \\endlastfoot",collapse=" ")
positions <- seq(from=10, to=dim(MatrixData)[1], by=10)
print(
  xtable(
      x = MatrixData
    , caption = "Example of longtable spanning several pages"
    #, label = "tab:MatrixData"
    , align = c("l|", rep("r", ncol(MatrixData)))
    , digits = c(rep(3, ncol(MatrixData)+1))
  )

  , table.placement = "H"
  , caption.placement = "top"
  , include.rownames = TRUE
  , include.colnames = TRUE
  , size = "small"
  , tabular.environment = 'longtable'
  , floating = FALSE
  , add.to.row = 
      list(pos = as.list(c(0,positions)),
             command = c(caption,rep("\\\\",length(positions)))))

@

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris for your answer. I'll it a try. I wonder if it possible to get this by using some code globally in preamble of Tex. Thanks